# undefined local variable or method `comment' for #<#<Class:0xb6d2fd0>:0xc077dd8>

Tags: ruby, partial

```
undefined local variable or method `comment' for #<#<Class:0xb6d2fd0>:0xc077dd8>
```

This is what my _comment.html.erb partial looks like

```
<div class="media">
<%= link_to '#', class: 'pull-left' do %>
    <%= image_tag(comment.user.avatar.small.url) if comment.user.avatar? %>
<% end %>
<div class="media-body">
    <small>
        <%= comment.user.name %> commented <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
        <% if policy(comment).destroy? %>
            | <%= link_to "Delete", [@topic, @post, comment], method: :delete %>
        <% end %>
    </small>
</div>
```

The create section of my comments_controller.rb

```
def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
@comment.post = @post 
authorize @comment 

if @comment.save
    redirect_to @post, notice: "Comment was saved successfully."
else
    flash[:error] = "Error creating comment. Please try again."
    render :new
end
```

end

and how I rendered in my posts#show view

```
<div>
    <%= render :partial => "comments/comment", local: {comment: @comment} %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing any locals to this partial:

```
<%= render :partial => "comments/comment" %>
```

You'd want to do this:

```
<%= render :partial => "comments/comment", :locals => { :comment => @comment } %>
```

Or use the shortcut:

```
<%= render 'comments/comment', :comment => @comment %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a local variable named `comment` in your `_comment.html.erb` partial.

You'll need to pass the `@comment` from your controller like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "comments/comment", locals: { comment: @comment } %>
```

Take a look at [Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) Rails Guide for more info.

Comment: When I do this, I get 
    undefined method `avatar?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: is `@comment.user` being set correctly? check your `current_user`

Comment: @comment.user is set to current_user in my comments_controller

Comment: where is `current_user` coming from? are you calling `.avatar?` on something you shouldn't be? this is basic debugging, check your code